# Rust russh async read/write

Tags: rust, borrow

Hey I started with rust and I am trying to implement a SSH passthrough program.
I want to just pass through all stdin via ssh to a remote server and print the stdout.
The problem now is the return value of some commands are not terminating but are streaming.

My current not working approach is this:

```rust
async fn start_ssh_driver(host: String, user: String, private_key_path: String, run_command: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    
    // Open SSH Session
    let key_pair = load_secret_key(private_key_path, None)?;
    let config = client::Config {
        connection_timeout: Some(Duration::from_secs(5)),
        ..<_>::default()
    };
    let config = Arc::new(config);
    let sh = Client {};
    let mut session = client::connect(config, SocketAddr::from_str(&host).unwrap(), sh).await?;
    let _auth_res = session
        .authenticate_publickey(user, Arc::new(key_pair))
        .await?;
    
    // Create new channel
    let mut channel = session.channel_open_session().await.unwrap();

    // Remote stdin
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("Waiting for data");
        while let Some(msg) = channel.wait().await {
            match msg {
                russh::ChannelMsg::Data { ref data } => {
                    match str::from_utf8(data) {
                        Ok(v) => println!("{}", v),
                        Err(_) => {/* ignored */},
                    };
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }
        println!("Exited reading");
    });

    channel.exec(false, &run_command).await.unwrap();

    let stdin = stdin();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(stdin);
    let mut line = String::new();
    loop {
        println!("> ");
        reader.read_line(&mut line).await.unwrap();
        channel.exec(false, &line).await.unwrap();
        line.clear();
    }
}
```

I get following error: `borrow of moved value: 'channel' value borrowed here after move`. Is there a way to copy the channel inside the task?

Comment: That can't be the error that you get, because there's no variable named `channel` in your source code that you've provided. Please create an MCVE and edit that and the full error message into your question.

Comment: I am sorry I did not update the whole snippet.

Comment: The example is still not proper, you use `channel` without declaring it first. You should copy & paste the example you confirmed to produce this error into the post instead of (re-)writing it in the browser.

Comment: sorry! next try, now it should be the same :))